# How to create an arch on a beveled cube

Tags: bevel

Seeking advice on how to create an arch at the top of this shape. When using bevel I cannot achieve a full arch.
[image: Text]

Trying to replicate the below sign

[image: Text]

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From the image in the question, it seems that the sides are rounded but the top is a flat arch.

You can start with this house like shape:

[image]

Bevel the edge loop (4 rings are enough):

[image]

Bevel the sides, and push it until it reaches the previous segments:

[image]

Removed the doubled vertices created above. Then add bevel weights to all the needed sides:

[image]

Add modifiers, bevel (based on the weights) and subdivision:

[image]

Eventually refine the topology, removing the ngons by making quads:

[image]

File with all steps included: [image]

Answer (score 2):

You should redo it another way, first create the general shape, then bevel:

Create a cube, scale it, create some loopcuts:

[image]

Move up the top face(s):

[image]

Select the edges that need to be round:

[image]

Bevel:

[image]